# TypeError: fn is not a function error, only in Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox

Creating a new Angular project without making a single change produces a browser console error, but only in Firefox:

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
```

The additional console output is:

```
main.js:17:9
 ready moz-extension://74483209-931f-4284-97e7-126f41531195/js/main.js:17
 <anonymous> moz-extension://74483209-931f-4284-97e7-126f41531195/js/main.js:126
 inject resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm:589
 AsyncFunctionNext self-hosted:810
```

I originally created the project in Angular CLI: 15.2.6 and Node: 16.x.x, then thought it might be a problem with an older version of node, so updated to Angular CLI: 15.2.6 and Node: 18.16.0, but still the same error.

It only exists in FF, no issue in Chrome. The page appearance does not have any visible flaws, unless you look at the browser console output. I tried it on Win10, Win11 & MacOS, and achieved the same result.

The exact steps to reproduce I used on 3 different environments:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
ng new FullStack.UI
cd FullStack.UI
code .
[open new terminal in VS Code]
ng serve --o
```

Comment: 2 things, not sure a period in a project name is a good idea and also, the error indicates maybe a weird plugin in firefox?